# How to assign a default string value to a Sqlite database column in UWP app?

Tags: sqlite, uwp

So i've a UWP which communicates with a database, i've a table which has a column names location. I want to assign a default value to that every time a a row is created.

The way i've created columns in the database is

```
//travel is a table name. id and location is a column in that table
public class travel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string location{get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public class travel
{
    public int id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string location { get; set; } = "";
}
```